# There was an unexpected error (404 Not Found) JSP and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I try to translate a project into Spring Boot, I get an error-I can not understand what I did wrong.
The suffix and prefix added to the property-file, tried to change the location of jsp,debager shows that in the controller's method comes.
What have I done wrong? I will be grateful for any help

Error:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Jul 17 00:45:23 EEST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). /Authorization.jsp

My current structure of project:
[image]
pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.solopov.hillel</groupId>
 <artifactId>uquiz</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

 <name>uquiz</name>
 <description>The project allows you to create and conduct surveys to anyone who wants</description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>


</project>
```

Spring Boot application.properties:

```
logging.level.root = info

spring.mvc.view.preffix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizzes?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

Sping Security configuration: (Just in case)

```
package com.solopov.hillel.uquiz.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select login,password,true from user where login=?")
             .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select login, role from user where login=?");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth", "/reg","/welcomepage").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("admin")
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/auth").usernameParameter("login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/auth")
                .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Method of Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/auth")
    public String authorization() {
        return "Authorization";
    }
```

Start class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UquizApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(UquizApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Comment: @AmithKumar No, it's not. It just looks like this. in fact, both dirrectory pats and other jsp on the same level. In that folder is header.jsp and footer.jsp.

Comment: @AmithKumar I have Spring Boot application: my configuration is application.properties and my application start from class UquizApplication, which i was adeed

Comment: @AmithKumar url,what i are hitting: /auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct typo in your property file:
`spring.mvc.view.preffix` to `spring.mvc.view.prefix`

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

you map the request to "**/auth**" and you access the request "**Authorization.jsp**". Your request should be **localhost:port/auth**

Comment: Why?  we must have to go to the jsp-page, going through the get-request.
And if we make a redirect to the address-how does it understand that it is necessary to get to Authorization.jsp?

Comment: address, like: localhost: 8080 / auth - formed by the built-in Apache Tomcat in Spring Boot

Comment: if you directly want to access the jsp page then use curl as like ip:port/<path of the jsp page> : -
        http://localhost:9109/tiles/common/body.jsp

Comment: I think there is a problem in the structure of location
 jsp- pages and the prefix.
Should work without "tiles / common"